# Overwrite Default Text On Marker PopUp In Google Map API Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I am using the below code to shop Road Maps between some markers on Google Map using its API on a WebPage. You can view it on [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/430/) too.

```
<style type="text/css">
html,body,#dvMap {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var directionsDisplay = [];
var directionsService = [];
var map = null;

function calcRoute() {

    var msg = "25.001807, 67.123459:25.007006, 67.076991:24.957115, 67.076278:24.945176, 67.084069:24.940619, 67.080735:24.936648, 67.076211:24.927262, 67.064335:24.918269, 67.053686:24.909177, 67.049781:24.900226, 67.044931:24.892076, 67.043592:24.880923, 67.039432:24.872733, 67.035963:24.859631, 67.015729:24.854257, 67.006481:24.848813, 66.996748:24.825830, 66.979450:24.818366, 66.975126";
    var input_msg = msg.split(":");
    var locations = new Array();

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < input_msg.length; i++) {
        var tmp_lat_lng = input_msg[i].split(",");
        locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(tmp_lat_lng[0], tmp_lat_lng[1]));
        bounds.extend(locations[locations.length-1]);
    }

    var mapOptions = {
        // center: locations[0],
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var i = locations.length;
    var index = 0;

    while (i != 0) {

        if (i < 3) {
            var tmp_locations = new Array();
            for (var j = index; j < locations.length; j++) {
                tmp_locations.push(locations[index]);
            }
            drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
            i = 0;
            index = locations.length;
        }

        if (i >= 3 && i <= 10) {
            console.log("before :fun < 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
            var tmp_locations = new Array();
            for (var j = index; j < locations.length; j++) {
                tmp_locations.push(locations[j]);
            }
            drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
            i = 0;
            index = locations.length;
            console.log("after fun < 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
        }

        if (i >= 10) {
            console.log("before :fun > 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
            var tmp_locations = new Array();
            for (var j = index; j < index + 10; j++) {
                tmp_locations.push(locations[j]);
            }
            drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
            i = i - 9;
            index = index + 9;
            console.log("after fun > 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
        }
    }
}


function drawRouteMap(locations) {

    var start, end;
    var waypts = [];

    for (var k = 0; k < locations.length; k++) {
        if (k >= 1 && k <= locations.length - 2) {
            waypts.push({
                location: locations[k],
                stopover: true
            });
        }
        if (k == 0) start = locations[k];

        if (k == locations.length - 1) end = locations[k];

    }
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    console.log(request);

    directionsService.push(new google.maps.DirectionsService());
    var instance = directionsService.length - 1;
    directionsDisplay.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        preserveViewport: true
    }));
    directionsDisplay[instance].setMap(map);
    directionsService[instance].route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            console.log(status);
            directionsDisplay[instance].setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', calcRoute);
</script>
```

Now my problem is that I want to show my own desired text on each marker label where currently Google is showing default address as shown in the below pic.

[image: Default Label On Marker]

I tried many things and google it but not able to add this feature in my code. So is this possible to write my own text there...???

*DEMO Text To Show As Per Their Lat Lon:*

```
var locations = [
    ['Ahsanabad Chowrangi', 25.001807, 67.123459, 1],
    ['Allah Wali Chowrangi', 25.007006, 67.076991, 2],
    ['Shafique Mor', 24.957115, 67.076278, 3],
    ['Sohrab Goth Flyover', 24.945176, 67.084069, 4],
    ['Ancholi', 24.940619, 67.080735, 5],
    ['Water Pump Chowrangi', 24.936648, 67.076211, 6],
    ['Ayesha Manzil Chowrangi', 24.927262, 67.064335, 7],
    ['Karimabad Chowrangi', 24.918269, 67.053686, 8],
    ['Liaquatabad 10 Number Chowrangi', 24.909177, 67.049781, 9],
    ['Lalo Kheet Daak Khana Chowrangi', 24.900226, 67.044931, 10],
    ['Teen Hatti Bridge', 24.892076, 67.043592, 11],
    ['Gurumandar', 24.880923, 67.039432, 12],
    ['Numaish Chowrangi', 24.872733, 67.035963, 13],
    ['Jama Cloth Market', 24.859631, 67.015729, 14],
    ['City Court', 24.854257, 67.006481, 15],
    ['Tower', 24.848813, 66.996748, 16],
    ['Nagina Center', 24.825830, 66.979450, 17],
    ['Kemari No. 1', 24.818366, 66.975126, 18]
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the text displayed for each marker, modify the `start_address` property of that leg in the directions response before calling the directions renderer.  To get the last point as well, also set the `end_address` property the value for the end marker of the next leg.

```
  for (var leg = 0; leg < response.routes[0].legs.length; leg++) {
    response.routes[0].legs[leg].start_address = markerText[instance * 9 + leg][0] + "<br>instance=" + instance;
  }
```

(the code above assumes an array `markerText` which contains the text you desire to appear for each marker).

[proof of concept fiddle using your array of locations](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/58ez4ukp/5/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsDisplay = [];
var directionsService = [];
var markerText = [
  ['Ahsanabad Chowrangi', 25.001807, 67.123459, 1],
  ['Allah Wali Chowrangi', 25.007006, 67.076991, 2],
  ['Shafique Mor', 24.957115, 67.076278, 3],
  ['Sohrab Goth Flyover', 24.945176, 67.084069, 4],
  ['Ancholi', 24.940619, 67.080735, 5],
  ['Water Pump Chowrangi', 24.936648, 67.076211, 6],
  ['Ayesha Manzil Chowrangi', 24.927262, 67.064335, 7],
  ['Karimabad Chowrangi', 24.918269, 67.053686, 8],
  ['Liaquatabad 10 Number Chowrangi', 24.909177, 67.049781, 9],
  ['Lalo Kheet Daak Khana Chowrangi', 24.900226, 67.044931, 10],
  ['Teen Hatti Bridge', 24.892076, 67.043592, 11],
  ['Gurumandar', 24.880923, 67.039432, 12],
  ['Numaish Chowrangi', 24.872733, 67.035963, 13],
  ['Jama Cloth Market', 24.859631, 67.015729, 14],
  ['City Court', 24.854257, 67.006481, 15],
  ['Tower', 24.848813, 66.996748, 16],
  ['Nagina Center', 24.825830, 66.979450, 17],
  ['Kemari No. 1', 24.818366, 66.975126, 18]
];
var map = null;

function calcRoute() {
  var msg = "25.001807, 67.123459:25.007006, 67.076991:24.957115, 67.076278:24.945176, 67.084069:24.940619, 67.080735:24.936648, 67.076211:24.927262, 67.064335:24.918269, 67.053686:24.909177, 67.049781:24.900226, 67.044931:24.892076, 67.043592:24.880923, 67.039432:24.872733, 67.035963:24.859631, 67.015729:24.854257, 67.006481:24.848813, 66.996748:24.825830, 66.979450:24.818366, 66.975126";
  var input_msg = msg.split(":");
  var locations = new Array();

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < input_msg.length; i++) {
    var tmp_lat_lng = input_msg[i].split(",");
    locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(tmp_lat_lng[0], tmp_lat_lng[1]));
    bounds.extend(locations[locations.length - 1]);
  }

  var mapOptions = {
    // center: locations[0],
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var i = locations.length;
  var index = 0;

  while (i != 0) {

    if (i < 3) {
      var tmp_locations = new Array();
      for (var j = index; j < locations.length; j++) {
        tmp_locations.push(locations[index]);
      }
      drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
      i = 0;
      index = locations.length;
    }

    if (i >= 3 && i <= 10) {
      console.log("before :fun < 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
      var tmp_locations = new Array();
      for (var j = index; j < locations.length; j++) {
        tmp_locations.push(locations[j]);
      }
      drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
      i = 0;
      index = locations.length;
      console.log("after fun < 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
    }

    if (i >= 10) {
      console.log("before :fun > 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
      var tmp_locations = new Array();
      for (var j = index; j < index + 10; j++) {
        tmp_locations.push(locations[j]);
      }
      drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
      i = i - 9;
      index = index + 9;
      console.log("after fun > 10: i value " + i + " index value" + index);
    }
  }
}


function drawRouteMap(locations) {

  var start, end;
  var waypts = [];

  for (var k = 0; k < locations.length; k++) {
    if (k >= 1 && k <= locations.length - 2) {
      waypts.push({
        location: locations[k],
        stopover: true
      });
    }
    if (k == 0) start = locations[k];

    if (k == locations.length - 1) end = locations[k];

  }
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  console.log(request);

  directionsService.push(new google.maps.DirectionsService());
  var instance = directionsService.length - 1;
  directionsDisplay.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    preserveViewport: true
  }));
  directionsDisplay[instance].setMap(map);
  directionsService[instance].route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      console.log(status);
      for (var leg = 0; leg < response.routes[0].legs.length; leg++) {
        response.routes[0].legs[leg].start_address = markerText[instance * 9 + leg][0] + "<br>instance=" + instance;
        response.routes[0].legs[leg].end_address = markerText[instance * 9 + leg + 1][0] + "<br>instance=" + instance;
      }
      directionsDisplay[instance].setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', calcRoute);
```

```css
html,
body,
#dvMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
```

**code snippet using same input list for all processing:**

```js
var directionsDisplay = [];
var directionsService = [];
var locations = [
  ['Ahsanabad Chowrangi', 25.001807, 67.123459, 1],
  ['Allah Wali Chowrangi', 25.007006, 67.076991, 2],
  ['Shafique Mor', 24.957115, 67.076278, 3],
  ['Sohrab Goth Flyover', 24.945176, 67.084069, 4],
  ['Ancholi', 24.940619, 67.080735, 5],
  ['Water Pump Chowrangi', 24.936648, 67.076211, 6],
  ['Ayesha Manzil Chowrangi', 24.927262, 67.064335, 7],
  ['Karimabad Chowrangi', 24.918269, 67.053686, 8],
  ['Liaquatabad 10 Number Chowrangi', 24.909177, 67.049781, 9],
  ['Lalo Kheet Daak Khana Chowrangi', 24.900226, 67.044931, 10],
  ['Teen Hatti Bridge', 24.892076, 67.043592, 11],
  ['Gurumandar', 24.880923, 67.039432, 12],
  ['Numaish Chowrangi', 24.872733, 67.035963, 13],
  ['Jama Cloth Market', 24.859631, 67.015729, 14],
  ['City Court', 24.854257, 67.006481, 15],
  ['Tower', 24.848813, 66.996748, 16],
  ['Nagina Center', 24.825830, 66.979450, 17],
  ['Kemari No. 1', 24.818366, 66.975126, 18]
];
var map = null;

function calcRoute() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(pt);
  }

  var mapOptions = {
    // center: locations[0],
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var i = locations.length;
  var index = 0;

  while (i != 0) {

    if (i < 3) {
      var tmp_locations = new Array();
      for (var j = index; j < locations.length; j++) {
        tmp_locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[j][1], locations[j][2]));
      }
      drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
      i = 0;
      index = locations.length;
    }

    if (i >= 3 && i <= 10) {
      console.log("before :fun < 10: i value " + i + " index value " + index);
      var tmp_locations = new Array();
      for (var j = index; j < locations.length; j++) {
        tmp_locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[j][1], locations[j][2]));
      }
      drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
      i = 0;
      index = locations.length;
      console.log("after fun < 10: i value " + i + " index value " + index);
    }

    if (i >= 10) {
      console.log("before :fun > 10: i value " + i + " index value " + index);
      var tmp_locations = new Array();
      for (var j = index; j < index + 10; j++) {
        tmp_locations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[j][1], locations[j][2]));
      }
      drawRouteMap(tmp_locations);
      i = i - 9;
      index = index + 9;
      console.log("after fun > 10: i value " + i + " index value " + index);
    }
  }
}


function drawRouteMap(routelocations) {

  var start, end;
  var waypts = [];

  for (var k = 0; k < routelocations.length; k++) {
    if (k >= 1 && k <= routelocations.length - 2) {
      waypts.push({
        location: routelocations[k],
        stopover: true
      });
    }
    if (k == 0) start = routelocations[k];

    if (k == routelocations.length - 1) end = routelocations[k];

  }
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  console.log(request);

  directionsService.push(new google.maps.DirectionsService());
  var instance = directionsService.length - 1;
  directionsDisplay.push(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    preserveViewport: true
  }));
  directionsDisplay[instance].setMap(map);
  directionsService[instance].route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      console.log(status);
      for (var leg = 0; leg < response.routes[0].legs.length; leg++) {
        response.routes[0].legs[leg].start_address = locations[instance * 9 + leg][0] + "<br>instance=" + instance;
        response.routes[0].legs[leg].end_address = locations[instance * 9 + leg + 1][0] + "<br>instance=" + instance;
      }
      directionsDisplay[instance].setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', calcRoute);
```

```css
html,
body,
#dvMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/58ez4ukp/6/))

Comment: added the code from the fiddle in a snippet in the answer.